# How to check if any value is Null in a table single row SQL

Tags: mysql

Each row of data in my table has about 8 elements. I want to check to see if any of the elements = NULL in a certain row, something like this:

```
UPDATE item_list SET is_tradable='no' WHERE item_name=:itemname AND element_1 = NULL OR element_2 = NULL or element_3... etc.
```

Can I do the same thing but check if any of them are NULL without going through each item? Like:

```
UPDATE item_list SET is_tradable='no' WHERE item_name=:itemname AND anyElement = NULL;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415820/mysql-is-it-possible-to-use-like-on-all-columns-in-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do what you want.  You need to list all the columns out.

However, your query will not do this.  You need to use `IS NULL` rather than `= NULL`:

```
UPDATE item_list
    SET is_tradable = 'no'
    WHERE item_name = :itemname AND
          (element_1 IS NULL OR element_2 IS NULL or element_3... etc.)
```

Also, remember the parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`.

There are ways to "simplify" the calculation.  For instance, `concat()` will return `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`:

```
UPDATE item_list
    SET is_tradable = 'no'
    WHERE item_name = :itemname AND
          concat(element_1, element_2, . . . ) IS NULL
```

As do the arithmetic operators (but your question does not state the type of the arguments).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way but you need to mention all the column names in null comparison something as

```
mysql> select least(null,'aa',null,'bb') ;
+----------------------------+
| least(null,'aa',null,'bb') |
+----------------------------+
| NULL                       |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here its getting the `least` values from a group of values.

So you may use as

```
WHERE item_name=:itemname 
AND least(element_1,element_2,element_3...) is null
```