# Use * Like operator to search all columns of table in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Here I have a question if it is possible to search all columns of my table in database in query, not using `Like` operator to my each column as:

```
SELECT * FROM banquets WHERE bqtID LIKE '%Value1' OR bqtName LIKE '%Value2';
```

But I want to use `*` instead of using multiple `Like` operator with my columns as like(Is it possible?):

```
SELECT * FROM banquets WHERE * LIKE '%Value%';
```

Since I've not tested it, I just want to know if it's possible or not. If not then how can I accomplish it? Or what can be alternative of that thing?

### Edit:

The question that is marked as duplicate is about using `WHERE` clause with mentioning all columns of table separately but I want to use it `*` in place of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible.

Try it here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in  with following request:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE * LIKE "%an";
```

You'll get:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* LIKE "%an"'.

Comment: how can I accomplish it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess there is no better way than doing: `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ContactName LIKE "%an" OR City LIKE "%an" OR ...;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415820/mysql-is-it-possible-to-use-like-on-all-columns-in-a-table

Comment: thanks for reply ... there is also providing columns **(`name`, `foo`, `bar`)** separately but I want to use `*`  in place of columns.